# How to create object from static method which accepts function

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

```
 static fromDto(httpClient: HttpClient, adalSvc: MsAdalAngular6Service) {
        return (dto: Dto) => {
          return new Note(httpClient, dto.xxx, adalSvc);

        };
   }
```

How to get the Note object from this static method in typescript. I have create a Dto object and trying to pass it to this method which will give me a Note object but can't seem to do that.

What I did was this

```
const notes = dtos.map(d => {
Note.fromDto(null, null).apply(d); });
```

can you please tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fromDto` returns a function whose signature matches what the `map` array function callback. At the moment your `map` callback is returning nothing, so will produce an array of `undefined` values.

You can use the long version and return from the callback:

```js
const notes = dtos.map(d => {
  return Note.fromDto(null, null)(d); 
});
```

Or the slightly shorter version with a single-line body:

```js
const notes = dtos.map(d => Note.fromDto(null, null)(d));
```

Or you can pass the function in as the callback:

```js
const notes = dtos.map(Note.fromDto(null, null));
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nsdpcr